# Get source element from Elastic-Search response with match all query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search to index data stored in my cassandra cluster.While fetching one record from Elastric Search cluster using the below query,

```
GET investhry/user/1/_source
```

I get the below result:

```
  {
  "password": "$2a$10$mE.qmcV0mFU5NcKh73TZx.z4ueI/.bDWbj0T1BYyqP481kGGarKLG",
  "lang_key": "en",
  "id": "1",
  "login": "system",
  "email": "hepccaf@gmail.com",
  "authorities": [
    "ROLE_ADMIN",
    "ROLE_USER"
  ],
  "lastname": "System",
  "activated": true
}
```

ie. only the data from `_source`

But while fetching all the data using this query

```
 GET investhry/user/_search
       {
      "query": {
     "match_all": {}
     }
   }
```

I am getting the whole response whereas I just want the `_source` element.

Can anyone help me with the query or method to get only the `_source` element with match-all query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter_path` parameter:

```
GET my_index/my_doctype/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source
```

Here we only want to keep the field `_source`.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering

Comment: I'm try this search query to get match_all:{ }  but i got this type of data      
 {
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": { }

Comment: Isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: In fact there his only the _source but it does include the path to reach it. Now I'm not sure if there is a way to remove this paths.